# Email sent from lotus notes which includes sent form not working in gmail

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, incoming-mail

While sending email from lotus notes to Gmail using Lotus Script, buttons are not visible in Gmail.

Comment: Action buttons? Those are specific to the Notes platform, and do not survive the translation to SMTP mail.

Answer (score 5):

As Anders says, Any standard or custom Action Buttons (at the top) will not be available in Gmail.  You would need to code your own Gmail interface to reproduce.

If you are talking about buttons in the actual rich text of the mail, these will definitely not get translated when the mail leaves and you should get a message saying...

> *"The following items cannot be sent or saved in MIME (internet mail) format."*

That would be a clear sign that you are going to need to take another look at your assumptions.

If you are planning a migration, you do need to check your assumptions (and your vendor's promises) carefully, there is a lot of infrastructure and functionality that is taken for granted in the Notes/Domino stack and just not available, or significantly different, in others.

Answer (score 2):

Stored forms are a feature that is unqiue to Notes.  They contain Notes design elements, formulas and scripts that execute Notes functions that are provided by the Notes API DLLs that are only available in the Notes client.  GMail doesn't know anything about them.  Outlook doesn't know anything about them.

But if you want to send them to someone who has a GMail address but who also has the Notes client, then there is a way to do it manually using the "Send this email to other Notes mail user(s) through the Internet" feature, which appears in the Advance tab of the Delivery Options dialog that you can bring up when sending a message.  There is no simple API for automating the mechanism that is used, but it can be done.  It requires creating a new empty database file with a special name (encap.ond), saving your document into that database, and then attaching the the file to a new message, which will be the one that you actually send.  I don't recall if any special headers are required for this, so if you want to pursue it you will have to do some investigation by using the manual process and checking out the full headers of the message on the receiving side.